# Realm - createOrUpdateAllFromJson for multidimensional JSON

Tags: android, realm

I tried using REALM ORM library for my project, and I have problem with createOrUpdateAllFromJson.

My JSON is:

```
[
  {
    "id":"487745454",
    "barcode":"84555453",
    "items":{
      "12456788":{
        "id":"12456788",
        "name":"Item1"
      },
      "12456789":{
        "id":"12456789",
        "name":"Item2"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id":"487745455",
    "barcode":"84555453",
    "items":{
      "12456788":{
        "id":"12456788",
        "name":"Item1"
      },
      "12456791":{
        "id":"12456789",
        "name":"Item10"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I can get barcode and id, but not get name from include object.
My class for get id and barcode is

```
public class Notepad extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;

    private String barcode;
    private RealmList<Items> items;
 }
```

And Item is:

```
public class Items extends RealmObject {

  @PrimaryKey
  private int id;
  private String name;
}
```

My question is, how get name from Item object throught createOrUpdateAllFromJson

I dont change API, which return this JSON.

Please help me

Comment: How are you accessing the JSON? I thing you should articolate more the quesiton.

Answer (score 0):

```
"items":{
    "12456788": {
        "id": "12456788",
        "name": "Item1"
    },
    "12456791": {
        "id": "12456789",
        "name": "Item10"
    }
}
```

This value for "items" is an object, but you try to parse it into a RealmList. This won't work. Also because your id's are strings and not ints. It would have worked if your json was

```
"items": [
    {
        "id": 12456788,
        "name": "Item1"
    },
    {
        "id": 12456789,
        "name": "Item10"
    }
]
```

I know you don't control the json structure but I strongly suggest you contact the person who does and ask him to change it.

The current json structure would translate into a `Map<String, Item>` in java and that is not something that is supported by Realm, unless you are going to parse the json manually.